# Is there any difference about the class java.net.InetAddress between 32bit OS and 64bit OS

Tags: java

```
InetAddress byName = Inet6Address.getByName(host);
```

Above code means, i want get the ip address by its name.

Then it runs successfully in the win2003 32bit OS,
but is catch UnknowHostException in the win2003 64bit OS.

So, I want to know "Is there any difference about the class java.net.InetAddress between 32bit OS and 64bit OS".

The OS is different, so, the InetAddress in the jre/rt.jar package is different.

Answer (score 1):

The internals/underlying implementation may or may not be sightly different for the 2 architectures.  I doubt it, but I can't tell you for sure.  More importantly though, in my experience it is unlikely to have anything to do with architecture specific implementation, and much more likely to be due to different networking setups in your 2 OSs.  Back in win2003 days, IPV6 was rather new and support patchy at best.

I would suggest checking/testing your IPV6 setup outside of java to make sure both machines are setup identically.

Comment: Through it calls Inet6Address.getByName(host), but the child class Inet6Address of InetAddress don't have the getByName(String) method, then it calls the InetAddress.getByName(String) method act in fact.

Answer (score 0):

No, UnknowHostException is thrown if the host name cannot be resolved. It has nothing to do with the 32 or 64 bit operating system.